# ORACLE TRIGGER or RAISE EXCEPTION When VIEW has data

Tags: oracle, exception, database-trigger

I want to monitor data in multiple tables. If all tables are ok the view has no data. otherwise error rows will appear in view. can I raise a trigger or exception if a row appear in view?
example:

```
Table A: value '123'
Table B: value '123'
```

View AB is

`select value from Table A, Table B where A.Value <> B.Value`

---

In the above view AB will have no value - Good
 if Table B has '1234' then view will have row showing '123' - this is an error flag since I'm expecting both tables to always have same data.

- Can I create a trigger or can i raise an auto exception whenever such mismatches happen?
- What else can be done so that i can be notified automatically as soon as this mismatch happen?

Comment: Well, if you are going to check the View to see if there's a mismatch, you won't need a Trigger, do you? You can check if record exists in the view and raise an exception from a procedure to notify every hour or so through a scheduled job?. But, if you want to ensure whether a value present in B should be there in A and vice versa whenever the value gets changed, you would need a `TRIGGER` on both table A and B on insert or update or delete.

Comment: unfortunately it mission critical .. cant allow time interval in reacting. Since many values from many tables are involved,cannot write triggers on each table.

Comment: I am also speculating, I could write for loop to see if any value int view, and if exit loop and execute error procedures. Not sure what may be impact of a continuously running for loop on the server

Comment: A view is just a stored query. It doesn't contain any data. So the only way you could do something would be to a job which runs every so often to select from the  view and send a message if their are records. *"unfortunately it mission critical .. cant allow time interval in reacting."*. Hmmm, this sounds complicated. Maybe you should explain the business rules you're trying to implement, and maybe somebody can come up with a solution for you.

Comment: *"Not sure what may be impact of a continuously running for loop on the server"*: Effectively you lose one CPU from your pool of available CPUs. If you are running on 64 CPUs then probably you can absorb it easily but if you are running on 2 CPUs you'd lose half your server. And 1 CPU? well that would be catastrophic.

Comment: Thank you Kaushik, and APC for your input. This gives me a lot to think over